# How to Display the Last Half of a String in the Results Returned by windows "findstr" command?

Tags: powershell

I have a windows 2012 instance on AWS in which I am trying to return the instance ID from the CLI. I can successfully return that info into a variable with this command:

```
$instanceId = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

I can then echo the contents of that variable and filter out the pertinent line:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> echo $instanceId | findstr  /b  /c:"Content "
Content           : i-4bee88888bd72g2a
```

The problem I have is that I wish to return only the string after the colon, so the output would look like:

```
i-4bee88888bd72g2a
```

What switch can I add to findstr to filter out that string? What is the Microsoft equivalent to sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell outputs *objects*, not *text*. When you run this command:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

it outputs a string representation of an object with a `Content` property. To select only the value of that property, you can use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` as follows:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
```

This tells PowerShell: "There's an output object, and I want only the value of its `Content` property."

You can assign this to your variable:

```
$instanceId = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
```

You can also probably write it this way:

```
$instanceId = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id).Content
```

(That is, the `( )` enclose an expression, and you are getting the `Content` property of the expression's output object.)

Comment: Thanks! The "Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content"  command worked fantastically.

Answer (score 0):

I may have been barking up the wrong tree with the command findstr. I found that I can display the exact string withe command select-string:

```
$instanceId | select-string -Pattern "i-"
```

Which returns the results:

```
i-4bee88888bd72g2a
```

(But it included blank lines before and after the results, which I may have to discard, TBD.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution that returns the exact results; it uses 'replace',  the MS version of 'sed':

```
$instanceId = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
$contentString = $instanceId | findstr /b /c:"Content "
$desiredresult = $contentString -replace "(Content           :)\s([a-z]+)",'$2'
$desiredresult
```

Which returns the exact results:

```
i-4bee88888bd72g2a
```